# -bash: hooks/post-receive: Permission denied

Tags: git, bash, amazon-ec2

I am setting up my EC2 with Git right now using http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto.

I get to this step;

```
 mkdir /var/www/www.example.org
 cat > hooks/post-receive
 #!/bin/sh
 GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f
 chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

However when I enter "cat > hooks/post-receive" or "sudo cat > hooks/post-receive", I get this error: -bash: hooks/post-receive: Permission denied

I have the SSH key setup with my git account so that is all set. What can I do to do this so I can move on. I can't move on from this step until I create that work tree.

Comment: What are the permissions on the `.git` directory, the `.git/hooks` directory and the `.git/hooks/post-receive` file?

Comment: not sure, how do I find that out?

Comment: `ls -ld .git .git/hooks .git/hooks/post-receive`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/5smi38

Comment: that is what comes up

Comment: You should be able to create the `post-receive` file as `root`. Double check that that doesn't work.

Comment: how do i create it as root? I have made one but idk if its as root

Comment: If you created that file at all that's fine but the permissions look like only root will be able to do that. `sudo` will do that but `sudo cat > file` only runs `cat` as root the redirection is done by the current user. You need to use something more like `sudo bash -c 'cat > file'`.

Comment: still says no permission

Comment: What did you run *exactly*?

Comment: sudo git bash -c cat > hooks/post-receive

Comment: -bash: hooks/post-receive: Permission denied
 is the result

Comment: I did the quote, and it still doesnt work

Comment: git: 'bash' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        stash

Comment: 1 more question, at this step, $ git remote add web ssh://server.example.org/home/ams/website.git do i repace the url with the https given to me in my git repository?

Comment: You use whatever URL/URI you are going to use to connect git to that repository, yes.

Comment: I have my SSH key setup why is it permission denied.

Comment: I don't know. A number of reasons are possible. But this has veered far off from the original question. I've added an answer to the original question. If you want further help with your ssh connection issues you can ask another question but I would suggest checking file/etc. permissions and that the key is right and the github troubleshooting documentation first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo cat > hooks/post-receive` runs only `cat` as the root user.

The redirection (and file creation) happens as the current user.

To have the redirection happen in the sudo context you need to run that whole thing as a script under a sudo shell.

```
sudo bash -c 'cat > hooks/post-receive'
```